Unit testing - PricebookEntry fails
issue is as following:
Code:
Pricebook2 pricebook = new Pricebook2(Name = 'Test Pricebook', IsActive = true);
insert pricebook;
PricebookEntry entry = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = pricebook.Id, UnitPrice = 22,  Product2 = new Product2(SBQQ__SortOrder__c = 1, Name = 'Test Entry 1', Prisfaktor__c = 'Test Prisfaktor 1', blng__TaxRule__r = new blng__TaxRule__c(blng__TaxableYesNo__c = 'Yes')), UseStandardPrice = false);
insert entry;

It fails on the insert entry, I tried also pricebook.procebookEntries.add(entry);
which it runnable but my data when im using:
List<PricebookEntry> entries = [SELECT UnitPrice, Product2.SBQQ__SortOrder__c, Name, Product2.Prisfaktor__c, Product2.blng__TaxRule__r.blng__TaxableYesNo__c, Product2.Ydelse_ID__c, CreatedDate FROM PricebookEntry];

I get no entries.

Please update your question. What does the error message look like?

Please look at the answer written by Ben Edwards here https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4KYQSA3

You can't insert a product by including it in the PricebookEntry (nor your blng__TaxRule__c)
PricebookEntry entry = new PricebookEntry(
Pricebook2Id = pricebook.Id, 
UnitPrice = 22,
// This part is the problem
Product2 = new Product2(SBQQ__SortOrder__c = 1, Name = 'Test Entry 1', Prisfaktor__c = 'Test Prisfaktor 1', blng__TaxRule__r = new blng__TaxRule__c(blng__TaxableYesNo__c = 'Yes')), 
UseStandardPrice = false);
insert entry;

DML only operates on the base object, not any data you put into related objects. The exception to that is if you use an Id, a field marked as an external id, or a standard field with the idLookup property. Salesforce will attempt to find the target record and relate it in those cases, but:

The record you're relating to needs to be inserted before you try to have Salesforce relate it
You can only specify a single field to attempt that auto-relation trick
The field used must be a unique value across the entirety of the records Salesforce can access for that SObject (recordtypes won't save you)

So you need to separately create (and insert) your blng__TaxRule__c and Product2, in that order, before you attempt to create your PricebookEntry.
Additionally, you need to create and insert a PricebookEntry for this test product using the standard pricebook before you'll be able to be able to insert a PricebookEntry using your test pricebook.

Even if I do it like this:
Product2 product = new Product2(...);
insert product;
With product, blng__TaxRule__c, procebook2, pricebookEntry I still get the issue when insert entry the pricebookEntry. all the other objects works fine.
PricebookEntry entry = new PricebookEntry(
Pricebook2Id = pricebook.Id,
Product2Id = product.Id,
UnitPrice = 22,
UseStandardPrice = false
);
insert entry;
This fails

@JariJonasLarsen Like I say in my last sentence, you need to insert a PBE for the standard pricebook (use Test.getStandardPricebookId()) before you can insert a PBE for your custom test pricebook. Those 2 PBEs need to be inserted in separate DML statements.
